# I don't want this method to return null if element is not found

Tags: java, automation, appium, xcuitest, page-factory

The below mwthod I am using to create dynamic elements in my page factory model. I am passing the IOSClassChain value as a string and then converting it into element. This works fine when the element is present on the page but this returns null when the element is not present. Below is the method:

```
public MobileElement mobileElementUsingIOSClassChain(String objElement) throws IOException {

    MobileElement objMobileElement = null;

    try {
        objMobileElement = (MobileElement) ((AppiumDriver) GetDriver()).findElement(ByIosClassChain.iOSClassChain(objElement));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Element not found");
    }
    return objMobileElement;

}
```

The value I am passing for objElement is:

```
String elementStr = "**/XCUIElementTypeButton[`label=='Name'`]"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what do you want it to return? Or should it not return at all and throw an Exception instead?

Comment: Use Optional<MobileElement>

Comment: Optionals are IMHO not an appropriate alternative for a reasonable exception handling....

Comment: if the element is not found then is it possible to create a dummy element that I can assign to 'objElement' something like this: `objElement = someDummyElementCreated` . If yes then how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

So what should it return instead? Either add a `return` statement in the catch block (and remove throws declaration) or remove the try-catch-block completly and throw the `Exception` to the caller.

It is btw considered bad coding style to use `catch (Exception e)`, catch a more concrete `Exception` instead (like `IOException`).

Comment: even if I write the return statement in catch block the method should have a return statement as its last statement otherwise it will show compilation error. Instead I wanted to know if we can create a dummy element here which I can pass to `objElement` so that this method will never return null.

Comment: Something like this: `objElement = dummyElementCreated`